# Am trying to run a test on my application but when ever i do a rails test command i get this fixture error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Am trying to run a test on my application but when ever i do a rails test command i get this fixture error

```
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError:         ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError


ERROR["test_should_get_contact", StaticPagesControllerTest, 0.8860733015462756]
 test_should_get_contact#StaticPagesControllerTest (0.89s)
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError:         ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError


ERROR["test_should_get_home", StaticPagesControllerTest, 0.8950023660436273]
 test_should_get_home#StaticPagesControllerTest (0.90s)
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError:         ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError


ERROR["test_should_get_static", StaticPagesControllerTest, 0.8991773026064038]
 test_should_get_static#StaticPagesControllerTest (0.90s)
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError:         ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError


ERROR["test_password_resets", PasswordResetsTest, 0.9067926732823253]
 test_password_resets#PasswordResetsTest (0.91s)
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError:         ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError


  89/89: [===========================================================] 100% Time: 00:00:00, Time: 00:00:00

Finished in 0.90997s
89 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 89 errors, 0 skips
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Services.yml file

```
one:
  service_company_name: MyString
  address: MyText
  year_formed: 1
  other_operational_countries: MyString
  about_company: MyText
  current_focus: MyString
  services: MyString
  estimated_booking: MyString
  financial_status: MyText
  location: one

two:
  service_company_name: MyString
  address: MyText
  year_formed: 1
  other_operational_countries: MyString
  about_company: MyText
  current_focus: MyString
  services: MyString
  estimated_booking: MyString
  financial_status: MyText
  location: two




  location.yml


one:
  country: MyString
  supra_region: MyString
  region: MyString

two:
  country: MyString
  supra_region: MyString
  region: MyString
```

Comment: So what do your test/fixtures files look like?

Comment: This is my Services.yml file.This is a model called services that stores all my services companies. Please let me know if you need any information..

Comment: you mean `services.yml` not `Services.yml` , right? Do you have fixtures `location.yml` ?

Comment: Yes I have a location.yml file. Thanks

Comment: They look ok, but YML files need to be indented with spaces,not tabs, that might be the problem?